# Selecting a default combobox value

Tags: c#, combobox

When my program loads, my combobox has no default value. I want the first one to be the default value when the program is loaded. How can I do that?

```
using Gtk;
using System;

class SharpApp : Window
{
    Label label;
    Label label2;
    Label label3;
    Label label4;

    public SharpApp() : base(" VALUTASOFFAN")
    {
        SetDefaultSize(411, 199);
        SetPosition(WindowPosition.Center);
        SetIconFromFile("..\\..\\web.png");

        DeleteEvent += new DeleteEventHandler(OnDelete);

        string[] valutor = new string[] 
        {    
            "YEN",
            "SEK",
            "EURO" 
        };

        //BOX1
        Fixed fix = new Fixed();
        ComboBox cb = new ComboBox(valutor);
        ComboBox cb2 = new ComboBox(valutor);
        Entry entry = new Entry ();
        Entry entry2 = new Entry ();
        cb.Changed += OnChanged;
        cb2.Changed += OnChanged2;
        entry.Changed += onChanged3;
        entry2.Changed += onChanged4;

        ComboBox combo = ComboBox.NewText(); 
        combo.Active = 0
        cb.Active = 0;

        label = new Label("-");
        label2 = new Label("-");
        label3 = new Label("-");
        label4 = new Label("-");

        fix.Put(entry, 100, 30);
        fix.Put(entry2, 100, 100);
        fix.Put(cb, 300, 30);
        fix.Put(cb2, 300, 100);
        //fix.Put(label3, 10, 30);
        //fix.Put(label4, 10, 100);
        Add(fix);

        ShowAll();      
    }

    void OnChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        ComboBox cb = (ComboBox) sender;
        label.Text = cb.ActiveText;
    }

    void OnChanged2(object sender2, EventArgs args)
    {
        ComboBox cb2 = (ComboBox) sender2;
        label2.Text = cb2.ActiveText;
    }

    void onChanged3(object sender3, EventArgs args)
    {
        Entry entry = (Entry)sender3;
        label3.Text = entry.Text;
    }

    void onChanged4(object sender4, EventArgs args)
    {
        Entry entry2 = (Entry)sender4;
        label4.Text = entry2.Text;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Application.Init();
        new SharpApp();
        Application.Run();
    }

    void OnDelete(object obj, DeleteEventArgs args)
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: The straightforward solution is to select the desired default value upon loading the program ... so what exactly is the question?

Comment: well, when the i run the program the combobox is blank and i havto click it and choose something in the list. I want it to load with the first thing in the string already loaded.

Comment: So, is the question *how to* select an item in the combo box in your code?

Comment: Please minimize your code sample so it contains just what is necessary to demonstrate your problem and nothing else. Also, please make sure your code is **compileable** and **executable** (to a point where we can see the problem). **Currently, it is neither.** Once you have done that, you might see that you have already solved your problem yourself, because as far as I can see, the fixed program does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

> I want the first one to be the default value when the program is
>   loaded. How can I do that?

Base of index of the given items

```
yourComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Base of [`.ValueMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.dynamics.mobile.framework.controls.combobox.valuemember%28v=mag.11%29.aspx) of the `ComboBox`

```
 yourComboBox.SelectedValue = 1;
```